# What's the difference between U+00A9 and U+24D2 of Unicode? (copyright symbol)

Tags: unicode

I need the copyright symbol like this 'ⓒ'. I did googling how to use this, and got the answer, Unicode `\u00a9`. But on some (Android) devices, it shows up bold. (I don't know how can explain... 'c' looks good but the circle around it looks bold.) So my colleague says to use `\u24d2`. Yes, it looks perfect on every device, but I don't know if it's proper. What's the difference between `\u00a9` and `\u24d2`?

Comment: "*But on some device, it shown up bold. (I don't know how can explain.. 'c' looks like good but just out circle looks like bold.)*" - post a screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unicode codepoint U+00A9 (©) is `COPYRIGHT SIGN`, and belongs to the ["C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement"](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) family of codepoints (U+0080 - U+00FF).

Unicode codepoint U+24B8 (Ⓒ) is `CIRCLED LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C`, and belongs to the ["Enclosed Alphanumerics"](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2460.pdf) family of codepoints (U+2460 – U+24FF), which includes all kinds of letters and numbers wrapped inside of circles, parenthesis, etc.

While U+00A9 and U+24B8 may visually appear to be similar, they are semantically very different things.

Comment: I suggest you add a third, the lowercase version of U+24B8: Unicode codepoint `U+24D2` is `CIRCLED LATIN SMALL LETTER C` (ⓒ) (lowercase). And reference [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_C).

Comment: So the OP should accept the visual disappointment and maybe file a bug against the font used by those Android distributions.

Comment: Yes, this would be a font issue, not a coding issue.